# symbolic derivative and integral

Tags: r, derivative, numerical-integration

I would like to integrate function `f4`  with respect to `x` and then find the derivative of the new function with respect to `t`. I can calculate the integral numerically. Is there any way to calculate this integral and derivative symbolically in R?

```
lambda=1
ci=1    
aa <- function(u,k,t){
    f4 <- function(x){
        f1 <- function(x){ lambda*exp(2*sqrt(lambda)*ci*t*cos(x)-
                         (1+lambda)*ci*t +u*(sqrt(lambda)*cos(x)-1))  }
        f2 <- function(x){cos(u*sqrt(lambda)*sin(x)) - 
                        cos(u*sqrt(lambda)*sin(x) + 2*x) }
        f3 <- function(x){ 1 +  lambda - 2*sqrt(lambda)*cos(x)   }
        (f1(x)*f2(x))/f3(x)
    }
    ((1/pi)*(integrate(f4, lower = 0, upper = pi)$value ))
}
D(aa,"t")
```

Comment: I think the more usual term for what you're calling "non-numeric" is "symbolic".  You can do some kinds of symbolic differentiation in R (`?D`), but for integration and more complex differentiation you need an interface to an external tool, e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Ben Bolker , I meant the symbolic derivative and integration.